# How to add footer to Ionic application using angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to add a footer to the ionic app. I am trying to add footer in an app.component.ts and want to use it for all pages instead of adding to all pages.

````
  <ion-router-outlet Id="content"></ion-router-outlet>
  <footer> footer
   </footer>
</ion-app>```
````

Comment: please go through - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/footer

Answer (score 1):

On your app.component.html you can add footer like this

```
 <main>
   <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
 </main>
 <footer></footer>
```

**app.componennt.css**

```
main{ margin:2rem auto; }
```